How to upload file from bubble.io to aws s3
I want to upload file to my s3 bucket from my bubble app
i have tryied to create api in aws api service and that api trigger the lambda function and that lambda function return the presigned url and with that url i post the file to my s3
but its not working

Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example to try to reproduce the error and debug it.
